# Get the display width of a string of characters

Tags: shell-script, unicode

What would be the closest to a portable way to get the display width (on a terminal at least (one that displays characters in the current locale with the correct width)) of a string of characters from a shell script.

I'm primarily interested in the width of non-control characters but solutions that take into account control characters like backspace, carriage return, horizontal tabulation are welcome as well.

In other words, I'm looking for a *shell* API around the `wcswidth()` POSIX function.

That command should return:

```
$ that-command 'ｕｎｉｘ'   # 4 fullwidth characters
8
$ that-command 'Stéphane' # 9 characters, one of which zero-width
8
$ that-command 'もで 諤奯ゞ' # 5 double-width Japanese characters and a space
11
```

One could use `ksh93`'s `printf '%<n>Ls'` that takes into account the character width for padding to `<n>` columns, or the `col` command (with for instance `printf '++%s\b\b--\n' <character> | col -b`) to try and derive that, there's a Text::CharWidth `perl` module at least, but are there more direct or portable approaches.

That's more or less a follow-up on [that other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244936/22565) which was about displaying text at the right of the screen for which you would need to have that information before displaying the text.

Comment: Relevant: http://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/#combining-characters-and-character-width

Answer (score 10):

In a terminal emulator, one could use the cursor position report to get before/after positions, e.g., from

```
...record position
printf '%s' $string
...record position
```

and find how wide the characters printed on the terminal.  Since that's an ECMA-48 (as well as VT100) control sequence supported by almost any terminal you are likely to use, it's fairly portable.

For reference

- [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Ps-n.1D1A)

```
    CSI Ps n  Device Status Report (DSR).
              ...
                Ps = 6  -> Report Cursor Position (CPR) [row;column].
              Result is CSI r ; c R
```

- [console_codes(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)
- [Standard ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)

Ultimately, the terminal emulator determines the printable width, because of these factors:

- locale settings affect the way a string may be formatted, but the series of bytes sent to the terminal are interpreted based on how the terminal is configured (noting that some people will argue that it has to be UTF-8, while on the other hand *portability* was the feature requested in the question).
- [`wcswidth`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcwidth.html) alone does not tell how combining characters are handled; POSIX does not mention this aspect in the description of that function.
- some characters (line-drawing for instance) which one might take for granted as single-width are (in Unicode) "ambiguous width", undermining portability of an application using `wcswidth` alone (see for example [Chapter 2. Setting Up Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-locale.html)).  `xterm` for instance has provision for selecting double-width characters for configurations needed this.
- to handle anything other than printable characters, you would have to rely upon the terminal emulator (unless you want to simulate that).

Shell APIs calling `wcswidth` are supported to varying degrees:

- [Text::CharWidth - Get number of occupied columns of a string on terminal](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CharWidth/CharWidth.pm)

  > This module supplies features ***similar*** as wcwidth(3) and wcswidth(3) in C language.
- [discussion](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/209475) for Ruby
- [API for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wcwidth/)

Those are more or less direct: simulating `wcswidth` in the case of Perl, calling C runtime from Ruby and Python.  You could even use curses, e.g., from Python (which would handle combining characters):

- initialize the terminal using [setupterm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.setupterm) (no text is written to the screen)
- use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.filter) function (for single lines)
- draw the text at the beginning of the line with [`addstr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.addstr), checking for error (in case it is too long), and then for the ending position
- if there is room, adjust the starting position.
- call [`endwin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.endwin) (which should not do a [`refresh`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.refresh))
- write the resulting information about the starting position to standard output

Using curses for *output* (rather than feeding the information back to a script or directly calling `tput`) would clear the whole line (`filter` does limit it to a line).

Comment: i think this must be the only way, really. if the terminal doesn't support double-width chars, then it doesn't much matter what `wcswidth()` has to say about anything at all.

Comment: In practice, the only problem I've had with this method is `plink`, which sets `TERM=xterm` even though it doesn't respond to any control sequence. But I don't use very exotic terminals.

Comment: Thanks. but the idea was to get that information _prior_ to display the string on the terminal (to know where to display it, that's a follow-up on the recent question about displaying a string on the right of the terminal, maybe I should have mentioned that though my real question was really about how to get to wcswidth from the shell). @mikeserv, yes wcswidth() may be wrong about how a specific terminal would display a particular string, but that's as close as you can get to a terminal-independant solution and that's what col/ksh-printf use on my system.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but wcswidth isn't directly accessible except via less-portable features (you could do this in perl, by making some assumptions - see http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CharWidth/CharWidth.pm).  The right-alignment question by the way could be (perhaps) improved by writing the string to the lower-left and then using the cursor-position and insert-controls to shift it to the lower-right.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - `fold` is apparently spec'd to handle multi-byte and *extended width* characters. Here's how it should handle backspace: *The current count of line width shall be decremented by one, although the count never shall become negative. The fold utility shall not insert a <newline> immediately before or after any <backspace>, unless **the following character has a width greater than 1** and would cause the line width to exceed width.* maybe `fold -w[num]` and `pr +[num]` could be teamed up somehow?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas It would be a horrible hack but you could set the foreground color to black, print the character, and then try to measure the width. Of course, this won't work for Emoji, which some terminals render in color. You could also scrape the display width for all unicode points for a range of terminals ahead of time, and store these in the program.

Answer (score 10):

For one-line strings, the GNU implementation of `wc` has a `-L` (a.k.a. `--max-line-length`) option that does exactly what you're looking for (except the control chars).

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea it would return the display width. Note that the FreeBSD implementation also has a -L option, the doc says it returns the number of characters in the longest line, but my test seems to indicate it's a number of bytes instead (not the display width in anycase). OS/X has no -L even though I'd have expected it to derive from FreeBSD's.

Comment: It seems to handle `tab` as well (assumes tab stops every 8 columns).

Comment: Actually, for more-than-one-line strings, I would say it also does exactly what I'm looking for, as in it handles the LF control characters _properly_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Are you still having the issue that this returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters?  I tested it on your data and get the results you wanted: `wc -L <<< 'ｕｎｉｘ'` → 8, `wc -L <<< 'Stéphane'` → 8, and `wc -L <<< 'もで 諤奯ゞ'` → 11.  P.S. You consider “Stéphane” to be nine characters, one of which is zero-width?  It looks to me like eight characters, one of which is multi-byte.

Comment: @G-Man, I was refering to the FreeBSD implementation, which in FreeBSD 12.0 and a UTF-8 locale still seems to be counting bytes. Note that é can be written using one U+00E9 character or a U+0065 (e) character followed by U+0301 (combining acute accent), the latter being the one showed in the question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas – I get `0` out of `printf $'\xe2\x80\xa6' |wc -L` on FreeBSD 11.2 vs `1` with GNU coreutils 8.30 on Debian Testing (11, Bullseye). That prints a horizontal ellipsis (U+2026 `…`) which is one character wide in a fixed-width font.

Comment: @AdamKatz, on FreeBSD  12.1-RELEASE-p6 and in a UTF-8 locale, I get 0 for `printf $'\xe2\x80\xa6' |wc -L` and `printf abc | wc -L` (I suppose those don't contain any line), but I get 3 for both `printf $'\xe2\x80\xa6\n' |wc -L` and `printf 'abc\n' | wc -L`, so still the number of bytes in the (properly delimited) line with the most bytes.

Answer (score 6):

In my `.profile`, I call a script to determine the width of a string on a terminal. I use this when logging in on the console of a machine where I don't trust the system-set `LC_CTYPE`, or when I log in remotely and can't trust `LC_CTYPE` to match the remote side. My script queries the terminal, rather than calling any library, because that was the whole point in my use case: determine the encoding of the terminal.

This is fragile in several ways:

- it modifies the display, so it isn't very nice user experience;
- there's a race condition if another program displays something at the wrong time;
- it locks up if the terminal doesn't respond. (A few years ago I [asked how to improve on this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/timing-out-in-a-shell-script), but it hasn't been much of an issue in practice so I never got around to switching to that solution. The only case I encountered of a terminal that doesn't respond was a Windows Emacs accessing remote files from a Linux machine with the `plink` method, and I solved it by [using the `plinkx` method instead](https://superuser.com/questions/317525/best-way-to-edit-remote-linux-files-on-emacs-from-windows/317707#317707).)

This may or may not match your use case.

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ z"$ZSH_VERSION" = z ]; then :; else
  emulate sh 2>/dev/null
fi
set -e

help_and_exit () {
  cat <<EOF
Usage: $0 {-NUMBER|TEXT}
Find out the width of TEXT on the terminal.

LIMITATION: this program has been designed to work in an xterm. Only
xterm and sufficiently compatible terminals will work. If you think
this program may be blocked waiting for input from the the terminal,
try entering the characters "0n0n" (digit 0, lowercase letter n,
repeat).

Display TEXT and erase it. Find out the position of the cursor before
and after displaying TEXT so as to compute the width of TEXT. The width
is returned as the exit code of the program. A value of 100 is returned if
the text is wider than 100 columns.

TEXT may contain backslash-escapes: \\0DDD represents the byte whose numeric
value is DDD in octal. Use '\\\\' to include a single backslash character.

You may use -NUMBER instead of TEXT (if TEXT begins with a dash, use
"-- TEXT"). This selects one of the built-in texts that are designed
to discriminate between common encodings. The following table lists
supported values of NUMBER (leftmost column) and the widths of the
sample text in several encodings.

  1  ASCII=0 UTF-8=2 latinN=3 8bits=4
EOF
  exit
}

builtin_text () {
  case $1 in
    -*[!0-9]*)
      echo 1>&2 "$0: bad number: $1"
      exit 119;;
    -1) # UTF8: {\'E\'e}; latin1: {\~A\~A\copyright}; ASCII: {}
      text='\0303\0211\0303\0251';;
    *)
      echo 1>&2 "$0: there is no text number $1. Stop."
      exit 118;;
  esac
}

text=
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  help_and_exit 1>&2
fi
case "$1" in
  --) shift;;
  -h|--help) help_and_exit;;
  -[0-9]) builtin_text "$1";;
  -*)
    echo 1>&2 "$0: unknown option: $1"
    exit 119
esac
if [ z"$text" = z ]; then
  text="$1"
fi

printf "" # test that it is there (abort on very old systems)

csi='\033['
dsr_cpr="${csi}6n" # Device Status Report --- Report Cursor Position
dsr_ok="${csi}5n" # Device Status Report --- Status Report

stty_save=`stty -g`
if [ z"$stty_save" = z ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: \`stty -g' failed ($?)."
  exit 3
fi
initial_x=
final_x=
delta_x=

cleanup () {
  set +e
  # Restore terminal settings
  stty "$stty_save"
  # Restore cursor position (unless something unexpected happened)
  if [ z"$2" = z ]; then
    if [ z"$initial_report" = z ]; then :; else
      x=`expr "${initial_report}" : "\\(.*\\)0"`
      printf "%b" "${csi}${x}H"
    fi
  fi
  if [ z"$1" = z ]; then
    # cleanup was called explicitly, so don't exit.
    # We use `trap : 0' rather than `trap - 0' because the latter doesn't
    # work in older Bourne shells.
    trap : 0
    return
  fi
  exit $1
}
trap 'cleanup 120 no' 0
trap 'cleanup 129' 1
trap 'cleanup 130' 2
trap 'cleanup 131' 3
trap 'cleanup 143' 15

stty eol 0 eof n -echo
printf "%b" "$dsr_cpr$dsr_ok"
initial_report=`tr -dc \;0123456789`
# Get the initial cursor position. Time out if the terminal does not reply
# within 1 second. The trick of calling tr and sleep in a pipeline to put
# them in a process group, and using "kill 0" to kill the whole process
# group, was suggested by Stephane Gimenez at
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10698/timing-out-in-a-shell-script
#trap : 14
#set +e
#initial_report=`sh -c 'ps -t $(tty) -o pid,ppid,pgid,command >/tmp/p;
#                       { tr -dc \;0123456789 >&3; kill -14 0; } |
#                       { sleep 1; kill -14 0; }' 3>&1`
#set -e
#initial_report=`{ sleep 1; kill 0; } |
#                { tr -dc \;0123456789 </dev/tty; kill 0; }`
if [ z"$initial_report" = z"" ]; then
  # We couldn't read the initial cursor position, so abort.
  cleanup 120
fi
# Write some text and get the final cursor position.
printf "%b%b" "$text" "$dsr_cpr$dsr_ok"
final_report=`tr -dc \;0123456789`

initial_x=`expr "$initial_report" : "[0-9][0-9]*;\\([0-9][0-9]*\\)0" || test $? -eq 1`
final_x=`expr "$final_report" : "[0-9][0-9]*;\\([0-9][0-9]*\\)0" || test $? -eq 1`
delta_x=`expr "$final_x" - "$initial_x" || test $? -eq 1`

cleanup
# Zsh has function-local EXIT traps, even in sh emulation mode. This
# is a long-standing bug.
trap : 0

if [ $delta_x -gt 100 ]; then
  delta_x=100
fi
exit $delta_x
```

The script returns the width in its return status, clipped to 100. Sample usage:

```
widthof -1
case $? in
  0) export LC_CTYPE=C;; # 7-bit charset
  2) locale_search .utf8 .UTF-8;; # utf8
  3) locale_search .iso88591 .ISO8859-1 .latin1 '';; # 8-bit with nonprintable 128-159, we assume latin1
  4) locale_search .iso88591 .ISO8859-1 .latin1 '';; # some full 8-bit charset, we assume latin1
  *) export LC_CTYPE=C;; # weird charset
esac
```

Comment: This was helpful to me (though I mostly used your [condensed version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10698/87770)). I made its usage a little prettier by adding `printf "\r%*s\r" $((${#text}+8)) " ";` to the end of `cleanup` (adding 8 is arbitrary; it needs to be long enough to cover the wider output of older locales but narrow enough to avoid a line wrap). This makes the test invisible, though it also assumes nothing has been printed on the line (which is fine in a `~/.profile`)

Comment: Actually, it appears from a little experimentation that in zsh (5.7.1) you can just do `text="Éé"` and then `${#text}` will give you the display width (I get `4` in a non-unicode terminal and `2` in a unicode-compliant terminal). This is not true for bash.

Comment: @AdamKatz `${#text}` doesn't give you the display width. It gives you the number of characters in the encoding used by current locale. Which is useless for my purpose since I want to determine the terminal's encoding. It is useful if you want the display width for some other reason, but it isn't accurate because not every character is one unit wide. For example combining accents have a width of 0, and Chinese ideograms have a width of 2.

Comment: Yeah, good point. It may satisfy Stéphane’s question but not your original intent (which is actually what I wanted to do too, thus my adapting your code). Hopefully my first comment was helpful to you, Gilles.

Answer (score 5):

[Eric Pruitt](https://www.codevat.com/) wrote an impressive implementation of `wcwidth()` and `wcswidth()` in Awk available at [wcwidth.awk](https://github.com/ericpruitt/wcwidth.awk). It mainly provides 4 functions

```
wcscolumns(), wcstruncate(), wcwidth(), wcswidth()
```

where `wcscolumns()` also tolerates non-printable characters.

```bsh
$ cat wcscolumns.awk 
{ printf "%d\n", wcscolumns($0) }
$ awk -f wcwidth.awk -f wcscolumns.awk <<< 'ｕｎｉｘ'
8
$ awk -f wcwidth.awk -f wcscolumns.awk <<< 'Stéphane'
8
$ awk -f wcwidth.awk -f wcscolumns.awk <<< 'もで 諤奯ゞ'
11
$ awk -f wcwidth.awk -f wcscolumns.awk <<< $'My sign is\t鼠鼠'
14
```

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/ericpruitt/wcwidth.awk/issues/1) asking about the handling of TABs since `wcscolumns($'My sign is\t鼠鼠')` should be greater than 14. *Update:* Eric added the function `wcsexpand()` to expand TABs to spaces:

```bsh
$ cat >wcsexpand.awk 
{ printf "%d\n", wcscolumns( wcsexpand($0, 8) ) }
$ awk -f wcwidth.awk -f wcsexpand.awk <<< $'My sign is\t鼠鼠'
20
$ echo $'鼠\tone\n鼠鼠\ttwo'
鼠      one
鼠鼠    two
$ awk -f wcwidth.awk -f wcsexpand.awk <<< $'鼠\tone\n鼠鼠\ttwo'
11
11
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the hints at possible solutions using `col` and `ksh93` in my question:

Using the `col` from `bsdmainutils` on Debian (may not work with other `col` implementations), to get the width of a single non-control character:

```
charwidth() {
  set "$(printf '...%s\b\b...\n' "$1" | col -b)"
  echo "$((${#1} - 4))"
}
```

Example:

```
$ charwidth x
1
$ charwidth $'\u301'
0
$ charwidth $'\u94f6'
2
```

Extended for a string:

```
stringwidth() {
   awk '
     BEGIN{
       s = ARGV[1]
       l = length(s)
       for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
         s1 = s1 ".."
         s2 = s2 "\b\b"
       }
       print s1 s s2 s1
       exit
     }' "$1" | col -b | awk '
        {print length - 2 * length(ARGV[2]); exit}' - "$1"
}
```

Using `ksh93`'s `printf '%Ls'`:

```
charwidth() {
  set "$(printf '.%2Ls.' "$1")"
  echo "$((5 - ${#1}))"
}

stringwidth() {
  set "$(printf '.%*Ls.' "$((2*${#1}))" "$1")" "$1"
  echo "$((2 + 3 * ${#2} - ${#1}))"
}
```

Using `perl`'s `Text::CharWidth`:

```
stringwidth() {
  perl -MText::CharWidth=mbswidth -le 'print mbswidth shift' -- "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, while `${#string}` gives you the length in character of the string like in ksh (or in bytes if the `multibyte` option is turned off), since version 4.3.7 (2008), and [this change](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2008/msg00449.html), when combined with the `m` parameter expansion flag, that becomes the display width (using the standard `wcwidth()` function underneath, even providing its own currently based on data from Unicode 9 for systems that don't have it). So there, it's just:

```
width=${(m)#string}
```

Note that ASCII control characters (including TAB, BS, NL, CR, NUL) and bytes not forming part of valid characters are counted as 1.

With older versions of zsh, you can use the `l` left-padding parameter expansion flag.

It pads according to the display width of the character, by default before version 4.3.3 and if you add the `m` flag since 4.3.3.

So one can calculate the width of a string with something like:

```
width() print $(($#1 * 3 - ${#${(ml[$#1 * 2])1}}))
```

Examples (with some comparisons with GNU `wc -L`):

```
$ width 'ｕｎｉｘ'
8
$ width $'Ste\u0301phane'
8
$ width 'もで 諤奯ゞ'
11

$ print 'a\tb'
a       b
$ width $'a\tb'
3
$ print 'a\tb' | wc -L
9

$ print 'a\bb'
b
$ width $'a\bb'
3
$ print 'a\bb' | wc -L
2
```