# How to erase unicode symbols in terminal?

Tags: terminal, unicode

Some symbols take up two character cells. Consider this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo '银^Htest'
echo 'а^Htest'
```

Output:

```
 test
test
```

How do I know their code points of fullwidth symbols? Some sort of regex for that? How do I count how many character cells a string takes? How do I erase everything that was outputted?

I'm using `xterm` if that matters.

**UPD** To give you the bigger picture, I'm trying to display progress, outputting some info, erasing it, outputting again... For that, I was moving cursor to the beginning of the line (`\r`), erasing the line with spaces (`tput cols`), and moving the cursor again (`\r`). But it turned out, that output might span several lines. So I decided to count characters, move back (`^H`), erase (output space as many times as the length of the string is), and move back again (`^H`).

Comment: Related, borderline duplicate: [Get the display width of a string of characters](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245013)

Comment: See also http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11909/focus=11910

Answer (score 2):

That is actually four questions:

1. How do I know their code points?
2. Some sort of regex?
3. How do I count how many character cells a string takes?
4. How do I erase everything that was outputted?

OP mentions xterm, but only the last two are possibly specific to xterm.

For (1) and (2), the echo command is not much help.  You are better off using [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html), which recognizes backslash escapes.  In some implementations (e.g., [GNU coreutils](http://www.agr.unideb.hu/~agocs/informatics/11_e_unix/unixhelp/unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi2855.html?printf%201)), that includes Unicode constants, e.g.,

```
printf '\u94f6\btest'
```

although for *regular expressions*, you are yet again better off using a scripting language such as Perl (which can handle UTF-8).

Further reading:

- [How do you echo a 4-digit Unicode character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash)
- [The printf command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)
- [What's the best way to embed a Unicode character in a POSIX shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652458/whats-the-best-way-to-embed-a-unicode-character-in-a-posix-shell-script)
- [Bash equivalent to Python's string literal for utf string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191110/bash-equivalent-to-pythons-string-literal-for-utf-string-conversion)

Questions (3) and (4) are more interesting.  First, the script cannot really tell how many character cells a string takes in advance, but can only measure it after the fact.  That is because the width is based on a combination of behavior of the terminal and the kernel.

- xterm uses [wcwidth](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcwidth.html) to decide how wide the character should be, with some issues about "wide" (double-width) fonts, and implementations of wcwidth reflecting developer's biases regarding the ambiguous-width Unicode values.  xterm can be configured (at runtime) to use its copy of Markus Kuhn's [implementation of `wcwidth`](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c); you are cautioned that it may not be complete nor match the actual system locale information.
- when xterm is told to erase part of a double-width character (as in the given example), it replaces the other part with a space.  Most other terminals imitating xterm do this (though in a quick check, I noticed one simply moving the cursor, causing the wide character and ASCII text to overlap).  If you *knew* that the value was double-width, you could simply adjust your notion of where the cursor was.
- the Linux kernel does not know anything about `wcwidth`.  Linux-based systems since [2004](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2004-04/msg00021.html) have a feature in `stty` called `iutf8`:

> which tells the kernel
>   that input is encoded in UTF-8, for proper editing support in canonical
>   input mode

- the Linux kernel feature is useful for editing *input*, because it helps the terminal driver do something reasonable when a backspace deletes the previous character.  However, there is no comparable feature for *output*.

You *can*, as suggested, use the cursor-position report (an escape sequence) to find the position of the cursor at different points.  But if you are going to use that to decide how to clear the line, it might seem more direct to just *move* to the position before printing the Unicode value, and start clearing from that point.

Alternatively, you could tell the terminal to save the cursor position before printing the wide character, and restore it (moving back).  That might seem cleaner and more predictable.  After restoring the cursor position, you could clear the line.  All three could be done using escape sequences — or [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html):

```
tput sc
printf '\u94f6'
tput rc
tput el
printf 'test'
```

Other than as a demonstration, this does have the drawback that the terminal would have only one saved-position for the cursor, and that to ensure clearing a single/double-width character, it is clearing an entire line.  But the cursor would end up in the "right" place.

- [Get the display width of a string of characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245013/get-the-display-width-of-a-string-of-characters)
- [terminfo - terminal capability data base](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) (for `sc`, `el` and `rc`)

Comment: The first two questions are basically, "What code points do fullwidth characters have?". With [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145712/52499) being the [best](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c) answer I could find. Then, as you could have already seen (in my question), the output might span several lines, so after all I most likely need to ask for cursor position to be able to find out which lines I need to erase. And then comes the scrolling issue. While outputting, the text might scroll. So, stored position might be no longer pointing to the beginning of the output. Any clues?

Comment: In a *shell script*, you're probably going to have problems.  You also probably should ask more focused questions, since there are a lot of possible answers.

Comment: How about `ruby` or `php`? Or you can probably use language of your choosing. Can you help me make it more focused? I don't really understand what I need to provide.

Comment: To get the width of a one-line string according to `wcwidth`, you can use the shell command `wc -L`.

Comment: Also let's not forget that an additional cell will be left empty at the end of the line if a wide character is printed there (it is wrapped to the next line). This makes tracking the number of required backspaces quite cumbersome. (Let alone that backspacing over a line boundary is another tricky story.)

Comment: [Indeed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/wc.c;h=94cbaff9ad6d8fbadff74ebb1ad4a1101438e8bd;hb=68f73f23866d6137e9c8d88d86073b33588d7b56#l669) (see `linelength` var), thanks, @egmont. But what's so tricky about backspacing over a line boundary? I'm already doing just that for a while, and have yet to run into issues with it. And do you have any clues to detecting scroll other than by counting characters?

Comment: Normally a backspace doesn't reverse wrap around a line wrap. It stays at the first column of the last line of your text. There's an escape sequence to enable that (I can't remember it or the feature's exact name off the top of my head).

Comment: Also note that unfortunately `wc -L`'s given behavior is specific to GNU wc.