# Pass length of argument into bash command substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I'm trying to write a quick bash function that populates a `README.md` with a `$1\n` followed by underscores the length of `$1`.

The code I found in other stackexchange questions showed that to print a character `<n>` times, use

```bsh
printf '=%.0s' {1..<n>}
```

and indeed, this works (obviously replacing `<n>` with a number).

To create my `README.md`, I thought the function would look something like this:

```bsh
make_readme() {
    echo "$1
$(printf '=%.0s' {1..${#1}})" > README.md
}

make_readme "Some project"
```

This, however, produces a file with this text:

```
Some project
=
```

As far as I can tell, `${#1}` within the `$(...)` is being replaced with the empty string.  My guess is that command substitutions get their own argument scopes, and since there are no arguments passed to the substitution, `$1` is being replaced with nothing.

I did finally finagle a couple workarounds:

```bsh
make_readme() {
    underline="printf '=%.0s' {1..${#1}}"
    echo "$1
$(eval "$underline")" > README.md
}
```

or

```bsh
make_readme() {
    echo "$1" > README.md
    printf '=%.0s' {1..${#1}} >> README.md
}
```

but it seems like there should be a way to do this in one line.

Comment: I first closed this as a dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738 but then saw that the question already used the `eval` approach taken in the accepted answer there.  The answers here should therefore be more directed to the last part of the question, i.e. how to make it nicer looking.

Comment: The "brace expansion" doesn't work with variables, only with (numerical) constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

make_readme () {
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$1" "$( eval "printf '=%.0s' {1..${#1}}" )"
}

make_readme 'Hello World!' >README.md
```

or, if calling an external utility is ok,

```
#!/bin/bash

make_readme () {
    # print $1, then replace all characters in it with = and print again
    sed 'p; s/./=/g' <<<"$1"
}

make_readme 'Hello World!' >README.md
```

Both of these generate a file called `README.md` containing

```
Hello World!
============
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid a call to `eval` but that `sed` answer works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: Or, on a similar concept as sed but without calling an external utility and that works in several shells: `printf '%s\n%s\n' "$1" "${1//?/=}"` (no eval :-)).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
make_readme () {
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$1" "${1//?/=}"
}

make_readme 'Hello World!' >README.md
```

Answer (score 2):

For your **actual problem** which is "given a string, produce a *same-length* string of =" I agree with other answers to modify the *string* using bash, zsh, tr, sed, etc.

But for your **stated question** which is "given a *number* produce a string of that length", the reason your approach didn't work is that bash does 'parameter expansion' which includes `${#1}` *after* brace expansion; see the [manual or info under Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions).

Some ways you *can* create a string given only the length:

1. use your `%.0s` trick but with the *program* `seq` instead of brace expansion (because command substitution creates a subshell that is executed first, and does the parameter expansion):

```
    printf '%s\n' "$1"; printf '=%.0s' $( seq ${#1} ); printf '\n'
```

2. use a 'variable width' format in `printf` to create padding, then modify it:

```
    # create a string of spaces equal to length of $1, then convert spaces to =
    t=$(printf '%*s' ${#1} ''); printf '%s\n' "$1" "${t// /=}"

    # create a string of zeros equal to length of $1, then convert zeros to =
    t=$(printf '%0*d' ${#1} 0); printf '%s\n' "$1" "${t//0/=}"
```

3. use perl, which is pretty common on systems nowadays, though not POSIX:

```
    printf '%s\n' "$1" "$( perl -e "print '='x${#1}" )"
    # quoting $(perl...) isn't needed when we know (all) the chars are =
    # but is good practice in general
    # note I reverse the more common method of singlequoting a perl script
    # with internal strings doublequoted, because I _want_ shell expansion
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
printf "%s\n%.*s\n" "$1" "${#1}" "$(printf "%.0s=" {1..30})"
Some project
============
```

Comment: Could you explain the last bit, the `{1..30}`?

Comment: @dfoverdx It creates a _long enough_ string of `=` and then chops it down to size using the length of the precision `${#1}` given on `printf`'s command line.

Comment: So it's not a general solution... only a solution that works with strings of length 30 or less?

Comment: @dfoverdx Yep. Increase to maximum expected string length.

Comment: *Is there* a general solution of this form?

Comment: @dx_over_dt Not with the `bash` shell I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use the `bash` shell, with `zsh` instead:

```
make_readme() printf '%s\n' $1 ${(l[$#1][=])}
```

Where `(l[length][string])` is the left-padding parameter expansion flag (here applied to no parameter at all).

To take into consideration the display width of each character, so it works better for text that contains zero-width or double-width characters:

```
$ make_readme() printf '%s\n' $1 ${(l[$#1*3-${#${(ml:$#1*2:)1}}][=])}
$ make_readme $'Ste\u0301phane'
Stéphane
========
$ make_readme 'ＦＯＯＢＡＲ'
ＦＯＯＢＡＲ
============
```

(those are U+FF21..U+FF3A double width capital English letters; your browser may not display them as exactly double-width, but your terminal should).

`${(ml:width:)1}` pads `$1` to `width`, taking into consideration the display width of each character, which allows us to compute the display width of `$1` by comparing the number of characters in `$1` with the number of characters if padded to twice that number of characters. See [Get the display width of a string of characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245013/22565) for details.