# Select lines based on length

Tags: text-processing, grep

I would like to use `grep` or another suitable tool to look for (and print) lines not based on some pattern, but on the length.

Assume I have a file that contains two lines, where

- Line 1: length = 300 characters
- Line 2: length = 120 characters

I am looking for a command that would only output line 2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### exactly 120 characters

With `grep`:

```
grep -xE '.{120}' < your-file
grep -x '.\{120\}' < your-file # more portable
```

With `awk`:

```
awk 'length == 120' < your-file
```

### from 0 to 120 characters

With `grep`:

```
grep -xE '.{0,120}' < your-file
grep -x '.\{0,120\}' < your-file # more portable
```

With `awk`:

```
awk 'length <= 120' < your-file
```

For *strictly less than 120*, replace 120 with 119 or `<=` with `<`.

### 120 characters or over:

With `grep`:

```
grep -E '.{120}' < your-file # lines that contain a sequence of 120 characters
grep '.\{120\}' < your-file # more portable
```

And some more alternatives:

```
grep -E '^.{120}' < your-file # lines that start with a sequence of 120 characters
grep '^.\{120\}' < your-file # more portable
```

```
grep -xE '.{120,}' < your-file # lines that have 120 or more characters
                               # between start and end.
grep -x '.\{120,\}' < your-file # more portable
```

With `awk`:

```
awk 'length >= 120' < your-file
```

For *strictly more than 120*, replace 120 with 121 or `>=` with `>`.

---

Those assume that the input is valid text properly encoded as per the locale's charmap. If the input contains NUL characters, sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters, lines larger than `LINE_MAX` (in number of bytes), or a non-delimited last line (in the case of `grep`; `awk` would add the missing delimiter), your mileage may vary.

If you want to do that filtering based on the number of bytes instead of characters, set the locale to `C` or `POSIX` (`LC_ALL=C grep...`).

To do the filtering based on number of grapheme clusters instead of characters and if your `grep` supports a `-P` option, you can replace the `E` with `P` above and `.` with `\X`.

Compare:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ echo $'e\u0301te\u0301' | grep -xP '\X{3}'
été
$ echo $'e\u0301te\u0301' | grep -xE '.{5}'
été
$ echo $'e\u0301te\u0301' | LC_ALL=C grep -xE '.{7}'
été
```

(that `été` is 3 grapheme clusters, 5 characters, 7 bytes).

Not all `grep -P` implementations support `\X`. Some only support the UTF-8 multibyte charmap.

Note that filtering based on display width is yet another matter, and display width for a given string of characters depends on the display device. See [Get the display width of a string of characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245013) for more on that.

Comment: Can you please add, how to grep less than n more than 120 characters.

Comment: Completely unrelated bit to the question itself, but I like it that `length==120` is unquoted here - nice code-golfing trick :)

Comment: @shivashiva, see edit.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I ended up adding the quotes for consistency with the other `awk` command lines.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, probably a good call, and to avoid confusion and extra questions about it.

Comment: thank you all, it was really a great help for me.

Comment: For "120 or more", don't you want `grep -xE '.{120,}'`?

Comment: @glennjackman that would also work. But `grep -E '.{120}'` for lines that contain at least 120 character looks simpler to me. `grep -E '^.{120}'` could  possibly improve performance for lines that contain fewer than 120 character, though could change the outcome if there are non-characters in the input.